# How can I count letters per word in a string using dictionary? (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, count, character, letters

So, I've found methods for counting the amount of words in a string and counting the amount of letters all together, but I have yet not found out how I can count the amount of letters per word in a string. Saying that the string would be f.

E.x

```
"I like cake"
```

I would like a result somewhat like this:

```
{"I":1, "like":4, "cake":4}
```

Probably not too hard, but I'm fairly new to coding, so I could use some help:) (btw, I cant use too many "shortcuts", since it's a task that I've been given.)

Comment: `len(s)` returns the number of characters in a string `s`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
count = {}

example = "I like cake"

for i in example.split():
    count[i] = len(i)

print(count)
```

Output :

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 letters_dict.py 
> {'I': 1, 'like': 4, 'cake': 4}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Dict comprehension, We can create dictionaries using simple expressions.
A dictionary comprehension takes the form {key: value for (key, value) in iterable}

`{word:len(word) for word in "I like you".split(" ")}`

Comment: wonderful one liner I love it , but  "(btw, I cant use too many "shortcuts", since it's a task that I've been given.)" was a condition of OP question

Comment: Code only answers are generally discouraged on Stack Overflow as they can be confusing for beginners. Please consider adding a small paragraph explaining what you are doing and how it works.